# How to proof: The set A × B is infinite if either A or B is infinite and the other set is not the empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm having some difficulty trying to prove that. 
Suppse $A$ is an infinite set and $B$ is the non empty set, I thoght of showing that the cartesian product of both sets have the same cardinality as $A$ has.
I'm trying to find a bijection in order to show it.

Leads and help will be very appriciated.
Thank you guys.

Comment: You only need to find an injection from either $A$ or $B$ (depending on which one is infinite) to $A\times B$.

Comment: every infinite set has a countable infinite subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Since none if the sets is empty, find an injection from $A$ into $A\times B$, and an injection from $B$ into the product. Then remember that a set with an infinite subset is infinite.

Comment: Regarding this: "Then remember that a set with an infinite subset is infinite.", Aint i supposed to use the fact the A has the same cardinality of the catasien prosuct and then clain that B is infinite? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use it, if you already know that. But did you prove that already?

Comment: I defined B such that it contains A and created an injection from A into A×B but can't do the other direction from  A×B into A.

Comment: Why are you *defining* $B$? It was given by the assumptions of the problem. Which is what makes it all the harder to prove that $|A\times B|=|A|$. Because what if $|B|>|A|$? Instead, if you want to show that something is infinite, just find an infinite subset of it.

Comment: I got very confused now.

Comment: $B$ is given in the question. You should not define it to be anything. And since $B$ is an arbitrary non-empty set, how can you be sure that $|B|\leq|A|$? If $|B|>|A|$, then $|A\times B|=|B|>|A|$. So the proof you are trying to come up with is doomed, without additional assumptions (which you can make, but have to explain). My hint, on the other hand, gives you a proof without the need for any additional assumptions, use it. You just need to show that $A\times B$ is infinite, not that $|A\times B|=|A|$.

Comment: Can I get some help writing it? I was trying to do it but something is just missing.

Comment: What did you write so far?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "an injection from B into the product". What do you mean 'the product'? What's the domain of B? AxB?

Comment: @Rizon: I don't even understand the question. Sorry.

Comment: You suggested finding 2 injection functions, one from A --> A X B, and the second from B --> ?

Comment: @Rizon: Also into A x B.

Comment: Great, so I defined these 2 injections. Where does it lead me..?

Comment: @Rizon: I don't know. Where do you want to go? Have you read my answer? Is your question even the same question as the OP? You're coming across as ungrateful, and not as someone who's trying to get help. Best of luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: Oh, I deeply apologize it was interpreted that way, none of my intentions whatsoever. I'm totally grateful for you even trying to help and getting back to this old question. Please allow me to rephrase - Yes, my question is exactly the same as the OP. I followed your suggestion and defined 2 injections, but I guess I didn't get the next step - "Then remember that a set with an infinite subset is infinite."

Comment: @Rizon: The image of an infinite set under an injective function is an infinite set.

Comment: So is the following a proper proof: 
Assume A is infinite and B is a non-empty set. 
Let b ∈ B (B is non-empty) 
Let f a function: f: A -> A X B, f(x) = (x,b). f is an injection. 
Let S be the image of f. 
The image of an infinite set under an injective function is an infinite set. 
To conclude, S is an infinite subset of A X B, so A X B is an infinite set.

Comment: @Rizon: Yes. Correct.